# How to know the next available file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Calling a function like `open` in C will return the next available file descriptor and use it up. Is there a way to simply ask my system what the next free `fd` will actually be instead? i.e not eating it up.

Comment: What could you do to make use of this information?

Comment: XY Problem. You (probably) don't wan't to know the next FD, you just think you do... What is the actual issue you think you can use the next FD to solve?

Comment: Mapping file descriptors when simulating some sort of new target on host a machine.

Comment: I still don't see how this is that useful, but you could simulate this by running from 0 up to some maximum value and calling an idempotent operation (perhaps `ftell(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)`) and looking at the error code, telling you if the file descriptor is in use or not.  This is a really weak approach, it's completely inviting a race condition, but if you had to, this might be close.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why you need to know *in advance* what fd will be provided by `open`.  When you're ready to use it, you find out by calling `open`, or one of a few other functions.

Comment: @SteveFriedl — either `fstat()` or `fcntl()` with an enquirer operation is a good way to discover if the file descriptor is open.

Comment: If you're simulating a target then fd wont map 1:1 with host. So if, for example, you call dup2, you may specify an available fd for the target, but it's in fact taken on the host. So you need to map to an available fd, which means you may need to know fd ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

By the time you ask what the "next" one is, another component (library, thread, etc) may immediately grab it and use it, so it will no longer be free.

The information on what the next unused descriptor is, is completely worthless, so it is not available.

Comment: That is wrong.   The file descriptor table is private, per-process(2).  Only operations within your process can affect what the next returned file descriptor is.  (2)- some clever OS's like plan9 and imitators permit two processes to *share* an fd-table, rather than provide a cloned fd-table as per UNIX std.

Comment: @mevets Yes, but libraries can use file descriptors without your really knowing about it, such as doing a DNS lookup; surely there are others, so it's not something the app has 100% control over.  It's certainly correct that they are per-process.